# Create a global variable rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to create a "global" variable. I create it in the file boot.rb.

RAILS_CAR_IMAGES = Rails.root.to_s + "/app/assets/images/" unless defined?(RAILS_CAR_IMAGES)

But it pops up an error.
"uninitialized constant Rails (NameError)"

Where should I create a global variable (contains path relative to the root folder) to save the uploaded images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `boot.rb` Rails has not been initialized ... Create a file in `config/initializers` with a name like car_images.rb and put the code there